# Check if label is in Grid Manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to detect my currently visible labels in a Python Tkinter grid. I'm talking about

```
L=Label(someFrame)
L1=Label(someFrame)
L.grid(row=1,column=1)
L1.grid(row=2,column=1)
L1.grid_remove()
```

Is there anyway to differentiate L1 from L as removed? I'm looking for something in Tkinter, not managing lists by myself. Possibly accessing the grid manager and seeing if a label is there?

Comment: AFAIK, widgets do not know if and where they are located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check using `grid_info()`. If a widget isn't in the grid then `grid_info()` will be a blank dictionary which will have a boolean value of `False`.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label1 = tk.Label(root)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = tk.Label(root)
label2.grid(row=1, column=1)
print(label1.grid_info())
print(label2.grid_info())
label2.grid_remove()
print(label1.grid_info())
print(label2.grid_info())
```

Output:

```
{'rowspan': 1, 'ipadx': 0, 'column': 0, 'sticky': '', 'pady': 0, 'columnspan': 1, 'in': <tkinter.Tk object at 0x0000000003411C88>, 'row': 0, 'ipady': 0, 'padx': 0}
{'rowspan': 1, 'ipadx': 0, 'column': 1, 'sticky': '', 'pady': 0, 'columnspan': 1, 'in': <tkinter.Tk object at 0x0000000003411C88>, 'row': 1, 'ipady': 0, 'padx': 0}
{'rowspan': 1, 'ipadx': 0, 'column': 0, 'sticky': '', 'pady': 0, 'columnspan': 1, 'in': <tkinter.Tk object at 0x0000000003411C88>, 'row': 0, 'ipady': 0, 'padx': 0}
{}
```

Comment: Perfect - simple and clean, what I needed.